# Spectrum of Dirac Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

The Dirac Hamiltonian is given by,
\begin{aligned}
H &=\sum_s\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}} E_{\vec{p}}\left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger} b_{\vec{p}}^{s}+c_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger} c_{\vec{p}}^{s}\right].
\end{aligned}
Now the Hamiltonian satisfies nice commutation relations with creation and annihilation operators as below and thus the spectrum of the Hamiltonian can be built from these,
\begin{aligned}
&\left[H, b_{\vec{p}}^{r}\right]=-E_{\vec{p}} b_{\vec{p}}^{r} \quad \text { and } \quad\left[H, b_{\vec{p}}^{r \dagger}\right]=E_{\vec{p}} b_{\vec{p}}^{r \uparrow}\\
&\left[H, c_{\vec{p}}^{r}\right]=-E_{\vec{p}} c_{\vec{p}}^{r} \quad \text { and } \quad\left[H, c_{\vec{p}}^{r \dagger}\right]=E_{\vec{p}} c_{\vec{p}}^{r \uparrow}
\end{aligned}
I am unable to derive these relations. Let me show you by trying the first one.
\begin{align}
[H,b^r_{\vec{q}}]&=\sum_s\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}} E_{\vec{p}}\left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger} b_{\vec{p}}^{s}+c_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger} c_{\vec{p}}^{s}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right]\\
&=\sum_s\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}} E_{\vec{p}}\left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right] b_{\vec{p}}^{s}
\end{align}
Now we know that
$$\left\{b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right\}=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(0)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta^{rs}$$
Thus,
$$\left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right]=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(0)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta^{rs}-2b^r_{\vec{q}}b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}$$
Using this relation I get,
\begin{align}
[H,b^r_{\vec{q}}]&=\sum_s\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}} E_{\vec{p}}\left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right] b_{\vec{p}}^{s}\\
&=\sum_s\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}} E_{\vec{p}}\left[(2\pi)^3\delta^{(0)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta^{rs}-2b^r_{\vec{q}}b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}\right]b_{\vec{p}}^{s}
\end{align}
Now I don't know how to get the commutation relation I quoted above. Can someone show where I got wrong and please show me the derivation of at least one of the commutators?

Comment: $[AB,C]=A\{B,C\}-\{A,C\}B$, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger} b_{\vec{p}}^{s}+c_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger} c_{\vec{p}}^{s}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right] = \left[b_{\vec{p}}^{s \dagger}\,\,,\,\,b^r_{\vec{q}}\right] b_{\vec{p}}^{s}$, you assumed that $b^r_{\vec{q}}$ commutes with all the other operators. However, it anti-commutes (and therefore does not commute).

Using the relation $[AB,C] = A\{B,C\} - \{A,C\}B$, you will get the right result.

Comment: Oh! I see. In the back of my mind I was still using the commutators and not anti-commutators between the operators. Thank you.